# OpenCL Particle system memory layout

Tags: opencl

I need some advice on some OpenCL code. I'm coding a particle system in OpenCL, drawn directly onto the gpu from OpenCL, so no copying to the CPU. It all works really well, but i have problem creating new particles.

I've allocated one large memory area with all the particle data in it on the GPU. One of the parameters of a particle is called isAlive, and decides weather its active. When i want to create a new particle i then find a particle that isn't alive, modifies its position to its starting position before setting it to isAlive true. This process is very expensive since i have to iterate through all particles to find the ones that arent active, and at the same time i have to make sure that several threads do not create the same particle at the same time (so i don't end up with more particles then i asked). 
Are there any good considerations, algorithms or tactics to solve this problem more elegantly and faster?

Comment: So you aren't copying the data back to the host, but are you calling different kernels from the host for each time step? Also, once a particle is dead, can it become alive again other than getting replaced by a new particle?

Comment: Yes, i'm never copying the data back to CPU. I repeat a sequence of kernel calls to update the particles every timestep. And yes i'm reusing dead particles again and again, but then its as a new particle in the pysical world, just replacing the memory area of the old, so it's not having any connection to the old dead particle.

Comment: Do you know anything about the number of dead particles at a given time? do you have enough memory to allocate a bit array to track the alive state? How many particles in total are you aiming for? Are you replacing all dead particles at the same time, or can some wait until a later timestep?

Comment: I could quilte easily find the number of dead particles I think yes. And yes I do have more memory available. Is it considarable faster to iterate a bit array and then lookup in the large array? It is very varying how particles die and live up. It's an interactive engine for some graphics. And sometimes I need to fill the screen very fast with lots of particles.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one approach I would try: separate the flag for isAlive from the rest of the data structure. This seems like a piece of data that is read often, but hardly written. Use a single uint to track the state of 32 particles. Use zero for alive, and 1 for dead -- essentially creating an isDead list. I assume you will have many more alive particles than dead ones.

The values can be read (32 at a time) into local memory when you need. This allows you to make a kernel that quickly iterates through the data, looking for a non-zero value. The big performance boost here comes with the dense data and thereby reducing the memory overhead of storing and loading the flags. This makes checking one of these values a much cheaper operation, allowing you to iterate through them more quickly. You will need to be careful when changing the 32 bit values so as to not corrupt the other data sharing the same uint (interlacing could help with this). The instructions clz, and popcount will be helpful when you need to narrow down the exact position of the 1 bits. [opencl 1.2 refcard](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/OpenCL-1.2-refcard.pdf)

possible optimization #1:
If you want, you can try interlacing the values so that the first uint is tracking indices 0,32,64,96,...,992 and the second uint represents 1,33,65,97,...,993 and so on. This may allow the work item that typically works on specific particles to read 32 consecutive isDead states. This could turn out to be more effort than it is worth, but that depends on your application.

possible optimization #2:
If the dead particles are really sparse, it might be worth it to track the isDead list on higher level. Using the same technique, it is easy to reduce the isDead bit/uint list again by a factor of 32. Each bit on the 2nd level represents the corresponding uint's state. ie: if any bits in uint N are set, bit N of this list will also be set. Only useful when a lot of zeros are expected in your data, but this extra step can save a lot of cycles searching for rare 'on' bits in the data. The total memory overhead for this including the original isDead data would amount to: memBits = ceil(particleCount/32) + ceil(particleCount/32^2), or about 128kb + 4kb for every 2^20 particles.

Using the above, it is possible to write a kernel that will return the number of dead particles in a given range, and quickly find one of the next available dead particles.

Comment: Thanks alot for all this information! I will try out this approach.